# jQuery stop() and animate() function issue

Tags: jquery, animation

This is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/poxgawf4/3/. It actually works, if you keep the mouse on the div and wait to execute the animation, BUT if you move your mouse quickly, it totally messed up everything. Do you have any idea why ?
This is the jQuery script:

```
$(".inno-bg").mouseenter(function () {

            $(this).css('background-image', 'none');
            $(this).css("background-color", "#1A6397");
            $(this).stop(true, true).animate({
                width: "320px"
            },{
                //easing: 'swing',
                duration: 500,
                complete: function(){
                       $(this).find("h2").stop(true, true).animate({
                            'marginTop': "-=60px"
                       });
                       $(this).find("p").fadeIn(1000);
                }
            });


        });
        $(".inno-bg").mouseleave(function () {
             $(this).find("h2").stop(true, true).animate({
                'marginTop': "+=60px"
            }, 200);
            imageUrl = "http://localhost/newsvro/images/pages/company/img_valori_innovation.png";
            $(this).css('background-image', 'url(' + imageUrl + ')');
            $(this).stop(true, false).animate({
                width: "160px"
            });
            $(this).find("p").hide();

        });
```

Comment: srry, check my fiddle again, i forgot to update it :)

Comment: everything well here... which browser/os do you use? Have you tried other browsers yourself?

Comment: please check my fiddle again, and see how my header jump down, if you move the mouse quickly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answer *does* explain the cause of the problem, but their answer will not cope with multiple instances of the animation.

It is best to avoid global variables for flags and use a state on the element itself. In this example I use a `completed` class to control the state of two instances (but a `data()` value would do):

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/poxgawf4/8/

```
$(".inno-bg").mouseenter(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.css('background-image', 'none');
    $this.css("background-color", "#1A6397");
    $this.stop(true, true).animate({
        width: "320px"
    }, {
        //easing: 'swing',
        duration: 500,
        complete: function () {
            $this.find("h2").stop(true, true).animate({
                'marginTop': "-=60px"
            });
            $this.find("p").fadeIn(1000);
            console.log('complete function called');
            $this.addClass("completed");
        }
    });
}).mouseleave(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.hasClass("completed")) {
        $(this).find("h2").stop(true, true).animate({
            'marginTop': "+=60px"
        }, 200);
        $this.removeClass('completed');
    }
    imageUrl = "http://www.esa.int/var/esa/storage/images/esa_multimedia/images/2014/02/gaia_calibration_image/14263603-2-eng-GB/Gaia_calibration_image_node_full_image_2.jpg";
    $this.css('background-image', 'url(' + imageUrl + ')');
    $this.stop(true, false).animate({
        width: "160px"
    });
    $this.find("p").hide();
});
```

I also chained the enter and leave methods, as they are on the same selector.

Answer (score 1):

I see the updated fiddle now. The problem is that in the first event (mouseenter) you start the second animation (`h2`) when the first one is completed. But on the way back, you start the animation no matter what. That means that if you do not complete the first animation fully, the h2 isn't moved up yet, because the `complete` callback is never called.

```
// use this toggle to check if the callback has been completed
var completeCallbackCalled = false; 

$(".inno-bg").mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).stop(true, true).animate({ width: "320px" }, 
        {
            // ...
        complete: function(){
            // This will ONLY be called when the animation is fully completed
            // Meaning; has NOT been stopped with the .stop() function
            completeCallbackCalled = true; // toggle
        }
    });
});

$(".inno-bg").mouseleave(function() {
    // now use the toggle to see if you need to run the animation
    // which pushes the h2 back down again
    if(completeCallbackCalled) {
        // animate here!
    }

    // reset the toggle
    completeCallbackCalled = false;
});
```

You should build-in a 'has been completed' toggle to check if you should execute the return-animation. Checkout the [revised fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/poxgawf4/5/) for a working example.

Comment: thx you for your understandable explanation :) I really appreciate your help !